# Apache Camel producers and consumers

Tags: messaging, apache-camel

I have difficulties wrapping my head around the concept.

I am trying to implement an endpoint that listens on a tcp port for incoming messages in a proprietary format, which would then transform the message and have camel take over the forwarding and routing.

Did I understand correctly that that the Producer is responsible for sending messages into the `Endpoint` and the `Consumer` receives them from that endpoint?

When studying the interfaces I couldn't figure out the message flow between those objects, especially on the consumer part. `Consumer` only defines `start()` and `stop()` methods...

When setting up a test on a skeleton implementation, `Camel` invoked `createProducer()` on the endpoint and `process()` on the producer object. After that it returned, swithout doing anything with the consumer or the processor associated with it.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I finally figured it out by looking at the Stream component.

Turns out that I made the mistake of thinking about the endpoint as something central thru which everything must go.

The simple answer is that the consumer receives data from an external system (listening on a server socket in my case) and the producer sends data to the external system.

Since my endpoint is read-only (it will not be used as the final destination of Camel routing process), I really do not need a producer (it should throw a RuntimeException if the system still tries to do it due to misconfiguration). A fitting example would be the camel-atom endpoint - you can read feeds but (as of 1.6.0) you cannot publish one.

Likewise, you only need a producer for a write-only endpoint which does not receive data from an external system (e.g logging).

Answer (score 66):

It's important to remember that an `Endpoint`, created by a `Component` (i.e. Endpoint Factory), can sit at *either* end of a Camel `Route`. If you put the *Component* at the start of a route then there must be an implementation of the `Consumer` part of the *Component*. This does the work of converting the specific input/request (like an HTTP request) into something generic - a Camel `Exchange` - that can travel down a *Route*. Whereas if you put the *Component* at end of a *route* then you must have an implementation of a `Producer`. The *Producer* does the work of taking the *Exchange* from the end of a *route* and converting it into something specific (like a JMS message).

I find the Fuse ESB documentation to be better (in general) than the [Apache Camel website](http://camel.apache.org/writing-components.html). From the [Fuse ESB Component page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB/4.4.1/html/Programing_EIP_Components/files/Component-Architecture-Factory.html):

> **Consumer endpoints** consume requests. They always appear at the start
>   of a route and they encapsulate the code responsible for receiving
>   incoming requests and dispatching outgoing replies.
>
> **Producer endpoints** produce requests. They always appears at the end of
>   a route and they encapsulate the code responsible for dispatching
>   outgoing requests and receiving incoming replies.

---

[image]

Comment: Nice clear explanation thanks.  The terms are often counter-intuitive, as a typical user of camel is thinking in terms of routes and messageExchanges, rather than authoring a new camel component. From the perspective of a messageExchange, the terms are the wrong way around.   A Consumer produces a messageExchange, while a Producer consumes a messageExchange.

Comment: As a newbie to Camel, I'm really confused by this answer.  If I look at the `org.apache.camel.Producer` interface, the only contracts it specifies are `createExchange` methods.  And looking at something like the `EventDrivenPollingConsumer`, the only thing that does with an Exchange is `process` it.  Doesn't an Exchange travel through a route - that's what Processors work with, so that was my impression.

Comment: @Snekse The descriptive part of the answer says exactly this. But in any case I don't think this technicality has much relevance for a conceptual understanding of producers and consumers.

Answer (score 8):

A Producer extends Processor which means it has a process method as well.

Check out the free chapter 1 in the Camel in Action book which tells a bit about those Camel concepts.
http://www.manning.com/ibsen/

And this tutorial is also excellent as it introduces those concepts in a steady pace
http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident.html