# Camels producer consumer confusion

Tags: java, apache-camel

The definition of producer and consumer in `Camel in Action` book is a bit confusing for me. I've already read two other answers for similar question however I still feel that it's not that.

> **A producer** is the Camel abstraction that refers to an entity capable
>   of creating and sending a message to an endpoint. Figure
>   1.10 illustrates where the producer fits in with other Camel concepts. When a message needs to be sent to an endpoint, the producer will
>   create an exchange and populate it with data compatible with that
>   particular endpoint. For example, a `FileProducer` will write the
>   message body to a file. A `JmsProducer`, on the other hand, will map the
>   Camel message to a `javax.jms.Message` before sending it to a JMS
>   destination. This is an important feature in Camel, because it hides
>   the complexity of interacting with particular transports.
>
> **A consumer** is the service that receives messages produced by a
>   producer, wraps them in an exchange, and sends them to be processed.
>   Consumers are the source of the exchanges being routed in Camel.
>   Looking back at figure 1.10, we can see where the consumer fits in
>   with other Camel concepts. To create a new exchange, a consumer will
>   use the endpoint that wraps the payload being consumed. A processor is
>   then used to initiate the routing of the exchange in Camel using the
>   routing engine.

[image]

Who's actually creating an exchange ? On which side of typical chanel of communication is producer and consumer ? From text above I can't really say who's responsible for that. It would be great if someone could provide a picture ( the one from book is unclear for me), where exactly is producer and consumer and explain how they work in an easy way. Maybe some example would be also useful.

Ok so maybe it would be better to give an example and someone could tell me how it works.
Imagine that we want to fetch files from a folder and put them on a JMS queue and from
there send them for further processing eventually saving on a disk.

[image]

Where exactly is producer, consumer according to my picture ? I realize what is a component and an endpoint.

Comment: I think the last diagram you added is too simplistic to properly explain this, but think about it this way: the consumer is whatever is reading your data. If the queue above is the final destination to your (processed) data, then the entity putting the data into your queue is the producer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119128/apache-camel-producers-and-consumers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are more or less right about your suspicion. Given the simple example:

```
CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    from("file:data/inbox?noop=true") // consumer
      .to("file:data/outbox");        // producer
  }
});
camelContext.start();
Thread.sleep(2000);
camelContext.stop();
```

In this example, we used a `RouteBuilder` to create a `Route` which, once the `CamelContext` is started, executes somewhat as follows:

1. Creates two `FileComponent`s to represent both locations.
2. Creates corresponding `FileEndpoint`s by querying the former components.
3. Create a `FileConsumer` for reading from `data/inbox`.
4. Creates a `GenericFileProducer` to write to `data/outbox`.
5. Hands control to the `FileConsumer` to start polling files from its directory which instructs its `Endpoint` to create an `Exchange` (as correctly shown in the picture). A `GenericFileMessage` is bound to this `Exchange`.
6. This `Exchange` is handed over to the `FileProducer`.

From this view, no exchange is created by the `Consumer`. I guess, at this stage of the book it does not yet make sense. And this is reflected in the text. However, looking at the implementation, both is equivalent when you look at the code:

The `Consumer` uses some `Processor` when sending the message is, in this case, represented by a `Consumer` which is then queried by the `Consumer` to generate an `Exchange` which the `Consumer` queries its `Endpoint` for which is then creating the actual `Exchange`.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps [the javadoc for Exchange class](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html) will clarify the ownership for you. Here is a snippet to answer your question on who creates the Exchange:

> An Exchange is created when a Consumer receives a request. A new Message is created, the request is set as the body of the Message and depending on the Consumer other Endpoint and protocol related information is added as headers on the Message. Then an Exchange is created and the newly created Message is set as the in on the Exchange. Therefore an Exchange starts its life in a Consumer.